# Need to create csv file from of content of 1 file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need help in writing a command or shell script that generates a csv file as per below details -

My file has content like -

```
+ Creates a new NotificationEventMapping

POST https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping [200 OK, 482B, 35ms]
+ Retrieves a NotificationEventMapping by Id_Mandatory
  
GET https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping/1043 [200 OK, 25.24kB, 50ms]
+ Updates the NotificationEventMapping identified by Id
  
PATCH https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping/1043 [200 OK, 491B, 37ms]
+ Deletes a NotificationEventMapping by Id
  
DELETE https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping/1043 [204 No Content, 146B, 10ms]
```

I need to filter above file and create a csv file in below manner -

```
POST,Creates a new NotificationEventMapping,200,35
GET,Retrieves a NotificationEventMapping by Id_Mandatory,200,50
PATCH,Updates the NotificationEventMapping identified by Id,200,37
DELETE,Deletes a NotificationEventMapping by Id,204,10
```

GREP/AWK/SED etc , anything can be used.

Thanks
Pallav

Comment: This really reads like a homework assignment - is that what it is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: no its not H.W assignment .. :-)..with awk command i can format 2nd lint to get POST, response code and time...but i am not able to get the API description which is present in line above the URL

Comment: python3 will be the easiest tool to do this with.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
        FS = "[][ ]"
}

! /^\+/ && ! /^\s+$/ && NF && NF - 1 {
        print $1, h, $4, $(NF - 1) + 0
}

/^\+/ {
        sub(/^\+\s+/, "", $0)
        h = $0
}' file
```

outputs:

```
POST,Creates a new NotificationEventMapping,200,35
GET,Retrieves a NotificationEventMapping by Id_Mandatory,200,50
PATCH,Updates the NotificationEventMapping identified by Id,200,37
DELETE,Deletes a NotificationEventMapping by Id,204,10
```

... and `file` is:

```
$ cat file
+ Creates a new NotificationEventMapping

POST https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping [200 OK, 482B, 35ms]
+ Retrieves a NotificationEventMapping by Id_Mandatory
  
GET https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping/1043 [200 OK, 25.24kB, 50ms]
+ Updates the NotificationEventMapping identified by Id
  
PATCH https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping/1043 [200 OK, 491B, 37ms]
+ Deletes a NotificationEventMapping by Id
  
DELETE https://sbc.com:1234/openapi-fun-events/api/v1/notificationEventMapping/1043 [204 No Content, 146B, 10ms]
```

---

**How it works:**

At the beginning `BEGIN` the output field separator `OFS` is set to a comma `,` to be used for separating fields in the output and the field separator `FS` is set to `]`, `[` and the white space   for splitting the fields in each input line that is read from the input file `file` … After that if the line being currently processed does not `!` start with a `+` sign `/^\+/` and is not all spaces `! /^\s+$/` and the number of fields `NF` evaluates to more than 0 and the number if the field before the last `NF - 1` evaluates to more than 0 as well, then print the first field `$1`, the value held in the variable `h`, the fourth field `$4` and the field before the last field `$(NF - 1)` forcing it to print only numeric integers by putting it in a mathematical calculation and adding a zero to it `+ 0` which will not alter the original number practically in this case in any way aside from stripping none numeric characters from it … On the other hand, if the line being processed starts with a plus sign `/^\+/`, then strip the leading plus sign with all continuous white space after it from the line `sub(/^\+\s+/, "", $0)` and then store that modified line in the variable `h` i.e. `h = $0` … And loop.

Comment: Thanks  for quick reply,Can u explain a bit how its working....specially middle part..

Comment: @guptpallav Sure, done that … I hope it’s clear.

Comment: Hi Rafte, thanks for the explanation, ..tricky part is  ! /^\+/ && ! /^\s+$/ && NF && NF - 1 {
        print $1, h, $4, $(NF - 1) + 0...but now i understood

Comment: @guptpallav - if Raffa helped you solve it, please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, it definitely helped me to solve the problem...